# Using the same bunch of attributes in many classes in C#

Tags: c#, attributes

I am trying to use the same bunch of attributes in many classes. How can I achieve this in C#?

If it is unclear what I am trying to achieve, please have a look at the example:

```
public class A
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    [Attribute1]
    [Attribute2]
    [Attribute3]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
    public string Property6 { get; set; }

    [Attribute1]
    [Attribute2]
    [Attribute3]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Basically `Foo` has the same bunch of attributes each time, but `copy-paste` is not an option, since it is too error-prone.

In this particular example it would work to inherit `A` and `B` from this class:

```
public class C
{
    [Attribute1]
    [Attribute2]
    [Attribute3]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

But having more properties like `Foo`, this cannot be achieved, since C# does not allow multi-inheritance.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Class C can have as many foos as you like. If you mean inheriting Foos one per class, then you'll want to use interfaces.

Comment: What are these attributes? Are they ones you control? You say that copy-paste is too error-prone... what sort of errors are you thinking of? Are these properties *inherently* linked, or do they just happen to have the same set of attributes? Without any context, it's very hard to suggest solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider making `C` an interface and adorning the interface property with your attributes - this solves the multi inheritance issue.

```
public interface IC
{
    [Attribute1]
    [Attribute2]
    [Attribute3]
    string Foo { get; set; }
}
```